# Cannot implement interface methods for multiple structs placed in the same package

Tags: go, interface

I have three files:

node.go:

```
type Node interface {
    AMethod(arg ArgType) bool
    BMethod() bool
}
```

anode.go:

```
type aNode struct {}

func AMethod(aNode ANode, arg ArgType) bool {
    return true
}

func BMethod(aNode ANode) bool {
    return true
}
```

bnode.go:

```
type bNode struct {}

func AMethod(bNode BNode, arg ArgType) bool {
    return true
}

func BMethod(bNode BNode) bool {
    return true
}
```

But I'm getting the error:

```
Nodes/bnode.go:16:58: AMethod redeclared in this block
    previous declaration at Nodes/anode.go:15:58
Nodes/bnode.go:20:60: BMethod redeclared in this block
    previous declaration at Nodes/anode.go:19:60
```

How do I validly implement an interface here?

Comment: That's not how you declare methods. See the [Tour of Go #Methods](https://tour.golang.org/methods/1), [Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#methods), or any other documentation

Answer (score 3):

Declaring a function that accepts a certain type does not make that function part of the type's [method set](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets) (meaning it does not help the type satisfy a particular interface).

Instead, you need to use the proper syntax to [declare a function as a method](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_declarations), like so:

```
type BNode struct {}

func (ANode) AMethod(arg ArgType) bool {
    return true
}

func (ANode) BMethod() bool {
    return true
}

type BNode struct {}

func (BNode) AMethod(arg ArgType) bool {
    return true
}

func (BNode) BMethod() bool {
    return true
}
```